# How to Use GetGeomtype Gdal Python

Tags: python, raster, gdal, filter

I am just wondering what I am doing wrong when trying to use the GetGeomType. I need to focus on separating layers from a pix file. Two categories are the bitmaps(which are vectors) and then the raster bands. I have imported gdal and ogr already.
Below is what I have tried so far and the errors I get when trying to use them.

```
    raster_image = gdal.Open(in_raster)
    band3 = raster_image.GetGeomType(3)
    print  band3
```

Above is how I am calling it but it gives me the error:

> AttributeError: 'Dataset' object has no attribute 'GetGeomType'

Then trying it by first getting the raster band and then checking the geom type I get:

```
    band3 = raster_image.GetRasterBand(3).GetGeomType()
    print band3
```

> AttributeError: 'Band' object has no attribute 'GetGeomType'

Comment: Are you using the GDAL development version (v2.0dev)? [PCIDSK (pix) vectors](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_pcidsk.html) are not supported in the current release (1.11) and below.

Comment: No I think I have to switch it from gdal to arcpy. Now im having another problem trying to use arcpy.RasterToNumpyArray with the pix file but it keeps on crashing and my boss would rather keep it running on 32bit python.

Comment: if you have a different problem you should ask a new question.